# Attribute in django django dispatch method

Tags: python, django

Below is the dispatch method in django view class

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Try to dispatch to the right method; if a method doesn't exist,
    # defer to the error handler. Also defer to the error handler if the
    # request method isn't on the approved list.
    if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
        handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed)
    else:
        handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

1.Can any one please tell me where the attribute **.method** defined ??which is used in the  conditional (if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:)

Comment: Here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py#L82

Comment: But we don't import WSGIRequest class in our View class

Comment: @shibleesaidul no neeed to import it, it's passed by django has an argument. Importing the class would be useless anyway, you need the real HTTP request (the bytes sent by the client) to instanciate a request object.

Answer (score 4):

It's defined as a part of the Django [request object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#attributes).

> **HttpRequest.method**
>
> A string representing the HTTP method used in the request. This is guaranteed to be uppercase. For example:
>
> ```
> if request.method == 'GET':
>     do_something()
> elif request.method == 'POST':
>     do_something_else()
> ```